# Will the property children be overwritten?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following React component:

```
export default function ElevationScroll({children}: PropsWithChildren<{ children: ReactElement }>) {

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });


    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    });
}
```

and have a question regarding to the argument definition `{children}: PropsWithChildren<{ children: ReactElement }>`.

First look at the definition of `PropsWithChildren`

```
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };
```

In the component argument, I have passed `{ children: ReactElement }` as the generic type, which expands to:

```
type PropsWithChildren<{ children: ReactElement }> = { children: ReactElement } & { children?: ReactNode };
```

Why it is allowed to define the property `children` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets see what is **NOT** allowed:

> Reminder: `{a:string} & {a:number}` results type `never`

```
type Prop<P> = P & { a: number };

// {a: string} & { a: number } = never
const bad: Prop<{a:string}> = {a: '5'} // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

But, when both types related, it works:

```
// { a: Number } & { a: number } 
const obj: Prop<{a:Number}> = {a: 5} // GOOD
```

---

Same goes for `ReactNode` and `ReactElement` relations (`ReactElement` is "stricter"):

- `React.ReactNode`: return value of **a component** (can return the string `"hello"`)
- `React.ReactElement`: return value of `React.createElement` (can't return the string `"hello"`)

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;

// Therefore
type ReactNode = ReactElement | ....
```